# Get Raw document from MongoDB through NoRM

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm

How to get raw document through NoRM driver of MongoDB or any other way?

Like i run command on shell

```
db.test.find({id:"235272479242"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NoRM equivalent to fetch a single document by Id would be:

```
 db.GetCollection<test>().FindOne(new { Id = "235272479242" });
```

Note that NoRM hasn't been updated in several years now and is [no longer supported](https://github.com/atheken/NoRM) by the original developer.

It would be worth looking into the [10gen-supported MongoDB C# / .NET driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center) which is actively maintained and supports the newest MongoDB server features.